# Firebird SQL + Firebirdsql.net provider Error "username and password are not defined". error on some machines

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I am working on an application that connects to a Firebird database through a TCP connection. The program works fine on my testing machine but when I try to install it on another computer I get this error:

> Firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient.fbexception: Your username and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a firebird login. ---> Your username and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a firebird login.

The strange point is when I copy the remote database.FDB file to my local computer, the program works perfectly (on localhost:c:\database.fdb).

but when I try to connect from an IP address i.e: (192.168.2.10:c:\database.fdb) i get this error. both the local machine and server machine has Firebird 2.0 installed.

Here's my connection strings for Firebird:

```
Userid=sysdba;password=masterkey;datasource=192.168.2.10:c:\database.fdb;Charset=NONE
```

This connection string also works on my test computer (where I connect it through an IP adress too), but I couldn't do anything on client machine.

I am not familiar with Firebird, but does it store database passwords on database.FDB or is it stored on some FDB file on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebird, password is defined in the Firebird instance (server), not in the database (FDB) file. The password in the remote machine for sysdba must have been changed from the default. You should either get the sysdba password from the server OR changing the sysdba password in the server.